# access a member of a nested struct

Tags: swift

I have a struct `Student`, it contains another struct `Address`:

```
public struct Student {
  public struct Address {
     public static let street = "xyz"
  }
}
```

In unit test of Student, I try to access street by:

```
 switch(someStr) {
     case is Student.Address.street:
      ...
    }
```

I get compiler error: `Static let 'street' is not a member type of 'Student.Address'` Why? How can I access the `street` through `Student` then?

(**This problem is only in unit test.**)

Comment: It should be `public static let street` – It that not your real code or did you ignore the compiler error?

Comment: It was just my typo in question, I do have `public static let street`, problem still exist.

Comment: Does the problem only occur in unit tests?

Comment: Yes, only in unit test

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: It should be `case Student.Address.street:` without the "is" – and that error is not related to unit tests, you would get the same error message in your main target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your have not defined its type `var` or `let` in Street variable.

Check below :

```
public struct Student {
  public struct Address {
     public static let street = "xyz"
  }
}

let street = Student.Address.street

switch(street) {

case Student.Address.street:
    print("vishal")
    break
default:
    break
}
```

Comment: I do have `public static let street = "xyz"`. It was just my typo in my question, problem still exist.

Comment: check my edited Ans its work for me. you need to use simple swift case for that.

Comment: have you import your project name into your unit test case class @Leem

Answer (score 0):

You missed a `let`:

```
public struct Student {
    public struct Address {
        public static let street = "xyz"
    }
}
```

Comment: I do have `public static let street = "xyz"`. It was just my typo in my question, problem still exist.

Comment: @Leem I cannot reproduce your bug, could you provide a sample project?